# iptables nat loopback for outside traffic

Tags: iptables, nat

I'm running DNS and NTP on my loopback interface. In order to work properly, those services need to be NAT outside with my eth0 interface. 
 (Basically all traffic generated from 127.0.0.1 with dest port 123 and 53 need to be translated with eth0 or IP 172.16.0.3)